# Recurrence relation, DiscretePlot with a variable initial value

Tags: plotting, manipulate, recursion, visualization

Ok, so I'm dealing with a recursive function (you can see it [here on MathExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2348452/recurrence-relation-monotonicity-and-convergence) as I have problems also on the analytic resolution) that I'm trying to solve numerically. The relation is

\begin{equation} \begin{cases} x_{n+1} = e^{-x^2_{n}}\\ x_0 =
 a\in\mathbb{R} \end{cases} \end{equation}

So I have $a$ that could be any real. Since I would like to visualise how  the function goes I made this code:

```
a = 1;
G[0] = a;
G[y_] := Exp[-G[y - 1]^2]
DiscretePlot[G[y], {y, 0, 30}, PlotRange -> {0.2, 1}]
```

with the test value $a = 1$, which produce this output:

[image]

Now, since $a$ is not 1 in general, I would like to make $a$ become a variable parameter to change and make something like [`Manipulate[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html) in order to see graphically how the relation changes by changing $a$.
I tried

```
G[0] = a;
G[y_] := Exp[-G[y - 1]^2]
Manipulate[DiscretePlot[G[y], {y, 0, 30}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}], {a, 0, 10}]
```

Obviously it didn't work at all. Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ClearAll[G, a] 
G[0] = a;
G[y_] := Exp[-G[y - 1]^2]

Manipulate[DiscretePlot[With[{a = a}, Evaluate@G[y]], {y, 0, 30}, 
  PlotRange -> {0, 1}], {a, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

Comment: I don't know why but your solution is not working, actually by changing $a$ nothing happens.

Comment: @opisthofulax Replace first line by `ClearAll[G, a]` i think will make it work

Comment: Yep, perfectly, thanks for your answer! If I may ask , do you know a say to plot this manipulate beside another manipulate (which this time is not a `DiscretePlot `, just a normal plot)? I tried with `Table` and `Show`, with not much success...

Comment: @opisthofulax, something like this: `Manipulate[
 Row[{DiscretePlot[With[{a = a}, Evaluate@G[y]], {y, 0, 30}, 
    PlotRange -> {0, 1}, ImageSize -> 200], 
   Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, Pi}, ImageSize -> 200]}, Spacer[10]], {a, 0, 
  10}]`?

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Best answer for you!

Answer (score 2):

You can include it in the definition:

```
G[0, a_] := a;
G[y_, a_] := Exp[-G[y - 1, a]^2]
Manipulate[DiscretePlot[G[y, a], {y, 0, 30}, PlotRange -> {0.2, 1}], {a, 1, 10}]
```

Comment: Smart solution!

Answer (score 0):

`RecurrenceTable` might be used:

```
Manipulate[ListPlot[Transpose[{Range[0, 30],
    RecurrenceTable[{g[y + 1] == Exp[-g[y]^2], g[0] == a}, g, {y, 0, 30}]}],
        Filling -> Axis, PlotRange -> {0, 1}], {a, 0, 3}]
```

Comment: Actually it is not given the proper result... Thanks anyway.